# Issue with jquery auto refresh function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was hoping that one of you might point me in the right direction with regards to an issue I am having with an jquery auto_refresh function - code below - > Uhm, it refreshes and everything, but sadly its ugly to look at. O.o When the refresh occurs it blinks out of proportion. Obviously there must be a much smoother way of doing this...

---

```
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#basic').load('resources_basic.php');
}, 1000);


$(function() {
$( "#draggable_res" ).draggable();
});
</script>
```

---

```
<div id="draggable_res" class="ui-widget-content">
<h5> Resources </h5>
  <div id="Accordion1" class="Accordion" tabindex="0">
    <div class="AccordionPanel">
      <div class="AccordionPanelTab">Basic Resources</div>
      <div class="AccordionPanelContent">
         <div id="basic"><?php include 'resources_basic.php'; ?></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
<table width="160" border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
          <tr>
            <td width="30"><img src="images/product/gold.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="Gold" /></td>
            <td width="110"><?php echo $row_resourcesbasic_rs['gold']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="30"><img src="images/product/wood.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="Wood" /></td>
            <td width="110"><?php echo $row_resourcesbasic_rs['wood']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="30"><img src="images/product/clay.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="Clay" /></td>
            <td width="110"><?php echo $row_resourcesbasic_rs['clay']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="30"><img src="images/product/stone.gif" width="30" height="30" alt="Stone" /></td>
            <td width="110"><?php echo $row_resourcesbasic_rs['stone']; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

**Thanks in advance :)**

Answer (score 0):

Some fading ? *This will make your refresh smoother*

```
$('#basic').fadeOut('fast');

$('#basic').load('resources_basic.php',function(){
   $('#basic').fadeIn('fast'); 
});
```

Comment: Tried that. :) still ugly :(

Comment: Ugly..?  How it look's like...?

Comment: Nevermind !!! I tried : Not exactly like yours... var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#basic').load('resources_basic.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to set initial size for the container where you're going to add dynamic data. Otherwise, it will resize every time it loads and blink.
The initial size can be best set via CSS, e.g.

```
#basic {
width: 100px;
height:100px;
background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: Tried that. It still resizes... even with initial size set.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the fade functions for some smoother transitions:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
     $('#basic').fadeOut(500).load('resources_basic.php').fadeIn('fast');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Tried that... I was looking for something more inconspicuous.